# VLOOKUP of Text is not working

Tags: google-sheets

Here Is how my google spreadsheet looks like

[image]

I'm trying to find the the Artifact ID (Column K) using the artifact name that is in G

So on A2 I'm trying to use this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(G2;$K$2:$L$39;1;FALSE)
```

$K$2:$L$39 is where the list of artifacts and ids is kept

But I'm getting this error

```
Error
The value "Vin.Api.Engagement.Content" has not been found by VLOOKUP. (translated from spanish)
```

Using the FIND functionality Is pretty clear that the value appears on that range

[image]

**I just found the solution and will post it below, but will keep this question here in case is useful to anyone else**

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` searches only usint the first column, so the artifact name had to be the first column and the ID the second one

So the formula had to be updated

```
=VLOOKUP(G2;$K$2:$L$39;2;FALSE)
```

And now it works
[image]

More details
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/vlookup-google-sheets-example/

Comment: One more thing; what to look for and the column to look in, often requires the data to be formatted with the same type and in the same manner, e.g. `=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A1;"@");...)` might help...